# Can't launch GIMP pre-installed via Flatpak on Linux Mint 19, how to debug?

Tags: linux-mint, troubleshooting, gimp, flatpak

I have quite a fresh installation of Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon with GIMP pre-installed via Flatpak:

### Basic info

```
$ flatpak info org.gimp.GIMP

Ref: app/org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable
ID: org.gimp.GIMP
Arch: x86_64
Branch: stable
Origin: flathub
Collection ID: org.flathub.Stable
Date: 2018-11-16 22:41:23 +0000
Subject: Update babl dependency. (e7b662db)
Commit: 1fcb2c783cf61e22ca6ed03df9f95d59785d5cbd668b50f9765693956f1eedeb
Parent: b6186ed16c732603f5c317bbc42717e500c0077251f9e8035a3266924b9cd55b
Location: /var/lib/flatpak/app/org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable/1fcb2c783cf61e22ca6ed03df9f95d59785d5cbd668b50f9765693956f1eedeb
Installed size: 213,3 MB
Runtime: org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.28
Sdk: org.gnome.Sdk/x86_64/3.28
```

2 days ago, everything worked fine. But today, I can't launch GIMP at all.

So far I haven't used Flatpak for anything myself, but since GIMP has been pre-installed this way, how do I troubleshoot the issue? Where to look for errors for instance?

---

### UPDATE #1

```
# cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i gimp

Dec  5 07:44:14 dell-7577 systemd[1545]: flatpak-org.gimp.GIMP-3662.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: Permission denied
Dec  5 07:44:14 dell-7577 systemd[1545]: flatpak-org.gimp.GIMP-3662.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Dec  5 07:44:14 dell-7577 systemd[1545]: Failed to start flatpak-org.gimp.GIMP-3662.scope.
```

---

### UPDATE #2

Based on this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flathub/org.gimp.GIMP/issues/23), I have added:

```
systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=1
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

and updated GRUB.

Now, in the ticket, it is written that this shall change the error message, whereas in my case it stays the same.

---

### UPDATE 2019-Mar-19

```
vlastimil@dell-7577: /home/vlastimil $ flatpak --verbose run org.gimp.GIMP//stable

F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/vlastimil/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening system flatpak installation at path /var/lib/flatpak
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/vlastimil/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening system flatpak installation at path /var/lib/flatpak
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/vlastimil/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening system flatpak installation at path /var/lib/flatpak
F: Cleaning up unused container id 226323790
F: Allocated instance id 2308729120
F: Allowing host-fs access
F: Allowing x11 access
F: Running 'bwrap --args 31 /usr/lib/flatpak/flatpak-dbus-proxy --args=33'
F: Running 'bwrap --args 27 gimp-2.10'
```

and the `syslog` gets this information:

```
Mar 19 20:14:45 dell-7577 systemd[1893]: Started flatpak-org.gimp.GIMP-10983.scope.
Mar 19 20:14:45 dell-7577 kernel: [15121.717117] traps: bwrap[10992] general protection ip:7fa0e07588f0 sp:7ffc3d5ad230 error:0 in libc-2.27.so[7fa0e0718000+1e7000]
```

but there's more, I have successfully ran it with sudo which is probably not a good idea, but to exhaust all options:

```
sudo --set-home /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gimp-2.10 org.gimp.GIMP
```

---

### UPDATE 2019-Nov-19

I suspected some relation to this problem of the ESET NOD32 antivirus. I just needed to prove it. After stopping its service, the problem no longer persists, i.e. after:

```
sudo systemctl stop esets.service
```

the Flatpak's GIMP installation works normally.

I've notified the ESET team of this issue now.

Comment: Do you really need to use the flatpak version? IMHO it's just a stopgap measure for people with relatively old systems (Ubuntu 16.04...). If you have a recent version (and Mint 19.1 is) then you can run a standard version, which is much better integrated with the rest.

Comment: @xenoid Yep, always *the latest and greatest*. It's not about me, but the problem itself, I wanted it solved finally.